# How do I allow null in a datetime field with a CakePHP form?

Tags: jquery, forms, cakephp, datepicker

I have a database which has fields `start_date` (`datetime`, required) and `end_date` (`datetime`, can be null).  I am creating a form for users to enter data using CakePHP.  My form contains

```
echo $this->Form->input('start_date');
echo $this->Form->input('end_date');
```

which outputs 6 `select`s (Month-Day-Year Hour:Minute Meridian) with the current date/time already selected because the data type is `datetime`.  **If I want the user to be able to insert `null` for `end_date` (essentially not fill out the field), how do I change my form?**

*What I'd really want is basically a textbox with a jQuery calendar popup to insert the formatted datetime, so they could leave the textbox empty if they wanted.  I'm not entirely sure what to even look for, and I'm guessing it's in the documentation somewhere, but I'm just starting with CakePHP (so apologies as this is probably a basic issue).*

Comment: You have to also specified the 'allowEmpty' => true with fields in model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery datepicker with textbox for date field.

Try something like this

**PHP**

```
<?php  echo $this->Form->input('end_date', array(
              'type' => 'text',
              'label' => 'End Date',
              'class' => ' j-date',
              'div' => false
          ));
?>
```

You can add jquery datepicker with every date field by adding class j-date with the element as mentioned above

**Jquery**

```
<script>
      $(function() {
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.j-date').each(function() {
                $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
                                    changeMonth: true,
                                    changeYear: true
                                });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I hope this solution would be feasible for you. Thanks

Comment: Perfect.  It was the 'type'=>'text' that I was looking for I guess.  It was easy to integrate the jQuery after that. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Use empty key:

```
$this->Form->input('end_date', array('empty' => true));
```

or `'empty' => '-'` etc

This will create fields that will end up as NULL in the DB.

Comment: I'm going with the jQuery datepicker in the end, but this is a very simple fix for my issue, thanks!